# How do i correctly update the position and velocity of 100 class objects individually drawing with pygame?

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

I was watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhjuuHl6qHM by The Coding Train and i thought: "what if i made that in python?" I decided to use pygame for the graphics since i'm terrible at coding and very new too so that's all i really know. I set out to do it. But i quickly found out it was not possible for me. I still wanted to do one part of the video as a challenge. The part where he creates a bunch of circles, gives them all a random velocity and lets them go from the center of screen. So i created 100 'boids' with a random velocity vector and put their position, velocity and acceleration into a list. It opens a pygame window and creates the boids, even updating their position. Unfortunately the positions they have doesn't update correctly and they become a clump of circles that walkes in a single direction off the screen. Can anybody help me with this?

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals
import numpy

pygame.init()
screen = (1600, 1200)
display = pygame.display.set_mode(screen)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
boids = []
j = 0

class Boid:
    position = numpy.array([screen[0] / 2, screen[1] / 2])
    velocity = numpy.array([0, 0])
    acceleration = numpy.array([0, 0])

    def update(self):
        self.position += self.velocity
        self.velocity += self.acceleration

for i in range(100):
    i = Boid()
    i.velocity = (numpy.random.choice([-5, -4, -3. -2. -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) * (numpy.random.random(2,)) + numpy.array([0.5, 0.5]))
    boids.append(i)
    #print(numpy.random.choice([-5, -4, -3. -2. -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
    print(i.position, i.velocity, i.acceleration)

while True:
    j += 1
    display.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for n in range(len(boids)):
        pygame.draw.circle(display, (255 - n, 255 - n, 255 - n), (int(boids[n].position[0]), int(boids[n].position[1])), 20)
        Boid.update(boids[n])
        print(n, boids[n].position, boids[n].velocity, boids[n].acceleration)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    i.update()
    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
    if j == 5:
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
```

Comment: You might prefer to use `random.randrange( -5, 6 )` instead of `numpy.random.choice( [-5, -4, -3. -2. -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`position`, `velocity`, `acceleration` are [class attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables). Add a constructor to the class `Boid` and create [instance attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects):

```py
class Boid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = numpy.array([screen[0] / 2, screen[1] / 2])
        self.velocity = numpy.array([0, 0])
        self.acceleration = numpy.array([0, 0])

    def update(self):
        self.position += self.velocity
        self.velocity += self.acceleration
```

Class attributes are shared by all instances of a class. But instance attributes are unique to each instance. In your there is actually just one `position` shared by all instances of `Boid`.

---

For a random and different distribution of the x and y components you might use [`numpy.random.random_sample`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.random_sample.html):

```py
i.velocity = 5 * (numpy.random.random_sample((2)) - numpy.array([0.5, 0.5]))
```

Or even a solution with a random [unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) direction vector for a circular distribution:

```py
vec =  numpy.random.random_sample(2) - numpy.array([0.5, 0.5])
i.velocity = 5 * numpy.random.random(1) * vec / numpy.linalg.norm(vec)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it useful to still have the = numpy.array([0, 0]) after the self.attributes? Because to make it work i had to state those attributes again.

Comment: @MariekePasker Remove `self.velocity = numpy.array([0, 0])`, but move the "random" part to the constructor. e.g. `self.velocity = 5 * (numpy.random.random_sample((2)) - numpy.array([0.5, 0.5]))`